# Paracompact iff deformation retract of classifying space of every open cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, groupoids

[This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45994/69037) and its comments, suggest a cool characterization of paracompactness I have never seen before.

For a space $B$ let $(U_i)$ be an open cover. Form the groupoid $\amalg_iU_i\times_B \amalg_iU_i \rightrightarrows \amalg_iU_i$ and look at its classifying space $\mathbf B U$. If I understand correctly, [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45927/a-conceptual-proof-that-local-fibrations-over-paracompact-spaces-are-global-fibr#comment110580_45994) says the following are equivalent:

- B is paracompact;
- $B$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbf BU$ for any open cover.

Unfortunately, I can't fill in the proof in any direction. Are the above conditions equivalent? How to prove this?